# fabric8:deploy how to set user and password properties in goals?

Tags: java, maven, jbossfuse, fabric8

I am trying to deploy a bundle to remote JBoss Fuse 6.1. 
I use "fabric8-maven-plugin".
I am executing the following command

```
mvn fabric8:deploy -Dfabric8.profileVersion=1.0 -Dfabric8.jolokiaUrl=http://host:8181/jolokia -Dfabric8.parentProfiles=parent -Dfabric8.profile=child
```

It requires `<server>` section in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file for the server id: fabric8.upload.repo

Is it possible to set user and password in command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Fabric8 Maven Plugin, Specifying credentials from command line](http://fabric8.io/gitbook/mavenPlugin.html#specifying-credentials-from-command-line):

> *The **fabric8:deploy** goal will by default read the username and password from the local Maven `settings.xml` file. This may not be desired to store password as plain-text. The option `jolokiaUrl` can be used to specify the url for the remote fabric server including username and password. For example to use username `scott` and password `tiger` then type:
>
>   
>
>   `fabric8:deploy -Dfabric8.jolokiaUrl=http://scott:tiger@localhost:8181/jolokia`*

Comment: -Dfabric8.jolokiaUrl=http://user:password@host:8181/jolokia. thanks. But I still have exception: Maven settings file: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/settings.xml


There is no <server> section in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file for the server id: fabric8.upload.repo

You can enter the username/password now and have the settings.xml updated or you can do this by hand if you prefer.

Would you like to update the settings.xml file now? (y/n): [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE